# Ubuntu freezing randomly while mouse works

Tags: nvidia, performance, nvidia-geforce

Recently, I started working on Ubuntu and I'm having an issue where it freezes somewhat randomly. When my machine freezes, the keyboard and mouse buttons no longer respond, but the cursor itself can still move freely about the screen. On rare occasions, the cursor will freeze as well.

I'm worried that it might be due to my RAM usage. However, the freezes are erratic and occur across many usage scenarios so I have some doubts.

My specs:

- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (64-bit)
- 8gb RAM
- GNOME 3.28.2
- CPU Intel i5-6500 3.20GHz
- GPU GeForce GTX 1060

Comment: What about graphics? If you have a new(ish) Nvidia graphics you probably need to install proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a wireless mouse and/or keyboard, your problem might stem from electronic interference.  I've found that mouse problems of the sort you describe will disappear if you install your wireless receivers at the end of a short USB extension cord.